# @Transactional needs to rollback everything except one save in database

Tags: java, exception, rollback, java-annotations

I have a method:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void createFile(final String number) {
    try {
           //code to save values
           throw new Exception(number);
        } catch(Exception e){
             this.repository.save(e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

In the method **createFile** there are many database save operations which needs to rollback when an error occurs. Catch needs to save the error message in the table.

How can i rollback the whole transaction in case of Exception but still do that save/update this.repository.save(e.getMessage()); on the database? could anyone help me sort this out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are using Spring.

Split it into two methods. E.g., `createFile` with the try-catch which calls the other, e.g., `createFileWorker` with the `//code to save values`. Call `createFileWorker` from `createFile`. If both the methods are in the same class, e.g., `MyService`, you will have to use `@Lazy` to inject proxied `MyService` into `MyService` and you will have to call `createFileWorker` via this proxied lazy instance. The `createFileWorker` should be annotated with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`.

```
@Service
class MyService {

private MyService self;

public MyService(@Lazy MyService self) {
  this.self = self;
}

@Transactional
void createFile() {
  try {
    self.createFileWorker()
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    this.repository.save(e.getMessage());
  }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
void createFileWorker() {
  //code to save values
}

}
```

Comment: nice hack to prevent the self invocation/proxying problem, but 2 services still ok!?

Comment: That's not a hack. You could also use non-constructor autowiring, but having two services would be the poorer solution.

Comment: @wilx, Thanks for your solution. I have tried that. Still  I'm not able to save. It is getting rollbacked